# jquery 3.1.0 with ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-forms-plugin

I want to do a **progress bar** to my image upload form and I'm using **jquery 3.1.0** and **jquery-form**.

but i got this message

***$(...).ajaxForm is not a function***

here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#progress-bar').width('0%')
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      $('#progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');
      $('#status').html(percentComplete + '%')
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log("done");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<form action="..." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="banner_photo" id="banner_photo">
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Comment: I fixed your HTML to be snippet worthy and it works fine.  Maybe you're original local jquery wasn't loading or jquery.form.min.js not loading from the cdn (check the browser network tab for errors)

Comment: it's loading properly.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in the snippet?  It's working in the snippet.  Have a read of [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$('form')` returns a list of forms, even if there is only one.

Give your form an id, and use `$('#yourFormId')` instead.

Alternatively you could do something like that :

```
$("form").each(function(index){
  $(this).ajaxForm({...})
});
```

Comment: the same problem persists even that I add an ID to the form

Comment: @ilyesBourouba do you select your form by id using JQuery ?

Comment: YES.
<form id="ilyes_222">
$('#ilyes_222').ajaxForm({...})